# Событие при выборе элемента из списка combobox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть комбобокс на WPF. В боксе несколько значений нужно что бы при выборе одного запускался один метод а при выборе другого значения - соответственно другой метод. Какое событие мне для этого использовать?

Событие именно для MenuItem. Пробую Click или  MenuItem.Click но тогда выпадающий список комбобокса не возвращается обратно и выбранное значение не заполняет бокс.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmb_OperationType" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="303,101,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178">
    <MenuItem Header="Buy" Click="cmb_NumbersOrders_SelectionChanged">
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="Sale">
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="Transfer" Click="cmb_NumbersOrders_SelectionChanged">
    </MenuItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: А почему у вас в `ComboBox`'е `MenuItem`, а не `ComboBoxItem`?

Comment: @VladD Спасибо Разобрался уже

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался. Надо было делать так :

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmb_OperationType" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="303,101,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Buy" Selected="cmb_NumbersOrders_SelectionChanged" Width="168">
    </ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Sale" Width="168">
    </ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Transfer" Selected="cmb_NumbersOrders_SelectionChanged" Width="168">
    </ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```